# Swift - override a method in two subclasses of UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, refactoring

I'm using custom subclasses of `UITextField` and `UIButton` - `MyTextField` and `MyButton`.

In both, I'm creating a rounded edges in such way:

```
var round = true
override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
    super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
    layer.cornerRadius = round ? self.frame.height/5.0 : 0
}
```

I'm trying to find some generic way to make both classes have `round` field and to override `layoutSublayers(...)`. What would be a better approach than pasting the same code in every class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, if you want to have a really flexible way, you could use the view styling concept. Here is the simple implementation that you could start with:

```swift
typealias Style<T> = (T) -> Void

extension UIView {

    convenience init<V: UIView>(with styles: [Style<V>]) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        guard let view = self as? V else {
            assertionFailure("Could not apply style for \(V.self) to \(type(of: self))")
            return
        }
        styles.forEach { $0(view) }
    }
}
```

then declare some stylesheet

```swift
enum ViewStyle {

    static func rounded(radius: CGFloat) -> Style<UIView> {
        return { view in
            view.layer.cornerRadius = radius
            view.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }

    static let lightGray: Style<UIView> = { view in
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
let button = UIButton(with: [ViewStyle.rounded(radius: 5.0)])
let textField = UITextField(with: [
    ViewStyle.rounded(radius: 8.0),
    ViewStyle.lightGray
])
```

It would allow you to reuse predefined styles and mix them to achieve more complex setups without creating own custom subclasses. And of course, it's only a small teaser of what can be done, I encourage you to go deeper :)

Answer (score 1):

A. use extension
since the `UIButton` and `UITextField` are both the subclass of `UIView`, you can try to make an extension of UIView, with a method `func roundTheCorner()`, but you have to call the roundTheCorner in each layoutSublayers of your customized class. FYI: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html

B. use runtime to add customized property `round`, then use the method swizzling to replace the method layoutSublayers. which could be a little bit tricky.
FYI: https://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way is to write an extension on a class that both UIButton and UITextField inherit from, UIView.

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(_ round: Bool) {
      layer.cornerRadius = round ? self.frame.height/5.0 : 0
     }
}
```

And then call it somewhere in both your subclasses like

```
roundCorners(true)
```